# java.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file when java is added to path

Tags: java, ant, cmd

I am trying to input "build clean build deploy" on the command line but I'm getting the following error : java.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

I have added Java and Ant to my path, the command "Java -version" produces the version number so I know it has been correctly added to path. What is causing my error?

Comment: Try to set JAVA_HOME in your environment variable and check if it solves your problem.

Comment: I've already done that.

Comment: What is the exact comment you are giving in your command line?

Comment: build clean build deploy

Comment: If it is a ant script it should start with ant (ant build)

Answer (score 1):

In JAVA_HOME set path of JDK as shown below:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

In Path, set path of bin directoryAs shown below:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin

Answer (score 0):

You need to set JAVA_HOME and PATH in your environment variables. Make sure that the directory of your Java does not contain the space. In your Path, the url should be %JAVA_HOME%\bin. After setting them, open a new commander and check again.

Hope this help.

Comment: Nope still getting the same error, java itself works on the command line as I can check version etc.

Comment: Can you just run the command separately?! For example: ant compile or java javac a java class?!

Comment: That gives me a BUILD FAILED error which I don't think is related to the problem at hand.

Comment: "Build failed": means your machine recognizes JDK and Ant already. I think the problem is in your command. Can you double-check this ""build clean build deploy"?! I don't think there is any problems with your environment. :)

Comment: Yep double checked but still getting error, very strange.

Comment: I mean the problem with your command. Can it work with "build clean"?!

Comment: It seems like your build script does not work. Can you just use normal ant command?! like ant build?!